# Custom Signal with GTK3 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, gtk, signals, gtk3

I would like to emit a custom signal from a Widget in gtk3.
In GTK2, there was a function called `signal_new` to create a new signal.
You can see an example here: https://github.com/ruby-gnome2/ruby-gnome2/blob/ec373f87e672dbeeaa157f9148d18b34713bb90e/glib2/sample/type-register.rb

In GTK3 it seems this function isn't available anymore. So what is the new way to create custom signals in ruby's GTK3?

Comment: You need to create a new subclass of GtkWidget and, in its `class_init` function, call [`g_signal_new()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-new) passing the GType of your new class as the `itype` object. While there seems to be a facility for this in `GLib::Signal`, it isn't documented; you'll need to ask the maintainers of the ruby gtk3 binding.

Comment: I suspect (haven't used signal_new, and I'm not a Ruby user) all these functions are moved to GObject. There is a method called GObject.signal_new() in Python.

Answer (score 4):

GTK3 changed to using a `define_signal` method instead of `signal_new`. This method is called on class-level (much like something like `attr_accessor`).

Here's an example class, using a custom signal called `example`. I've adapted this from a [sample on the `glib2` GitHub repo](https://github.com/ruby-gnome2/ruby-gnome2/blob/23b38b3166d927e388963b491121523c10aba676/glib2/sample/type-register.rb#L35).

```rb
class ExampleClass < GLib::Object
  # To use define_signal, the class must first be registered with GLib's
  # type hierarchy.
  type_register

  # This declares the custom signal.
  define_signal(
    'example', # signal name
    nil,       # flags (combination of GLib::Signal's constants)
    nil,       # accumulator; apparently not supported
    nil        # signal return type, where nil is void
  )
end
```

By default, a signal's handler block accepts one parameter, which is the object which emitted the signal. If you'd like the signal to use additional parameters, you can pass extra arguments to `define_signal` with their types.

Once you've configured a signal, you can emit it using `signal_emit`:

```rb
example = ExampleClass.new
example.signal_emit('example')
```

If there were additional arguments to pass, their values can be passed as extra arguments to `signal_emit`.

This signal can be connected to just like any other GTK3 signal, using `signal_connect`:

```rb
e = ExampleClass.new
e.signal_connect('example') do |sender|
  puts "Handler 1, sent by #{sender}"
end
e.signal_connect('example') do |sender|
  puts "Handler 2, sent by #{sender}"
end
e.signal_emit('example')
```

This would output something like:

> ```
> Handler 1, sent by #<ExampleClass:0x0000564d436331e8>
> Handler 2, sent by #<ExampleClass:0x0000564d436331e8>
> ```

Again, if your signal uses additional parameters, they would be extra arguments passed to `signal_connect`'s block.

Comment: [glib2: add GLib::Object.define_signal](https://github.com/ruby-gnome2/ruby-gnome2/commit/919d92c3f6e97cc2aeac661390890eb1a7c3a3f5) is the commit where this was added. Good find!